# X11VNC - connection failed due to incorrect password even though password correct

Tags: ubuntu, windows, authentication, vnc, x11vnc

Running Xubuntu 20.04 as VM on top of Ubuntu Server 20.04 with bridged interface. I am able to connect to the VM via SSH (also using Putty on Windows 10 machine that will access the VM).

Using VNCViewer (part of the TigerVNC project) on a Windows 10 machine I entered the IP address of the VM. A popup for password is displayed where I enter the password but when I click connect I get

```
TigerVNC
An unexpected error occurred when communicating with the server:
Authentication failure: password check failed!
Attempt to reconnect?

                                                      [No] [Yes]
```

I installed `x11vnc` the usual way using `apt`. Following instructions online I created

- an encrypted password file

  ```
  sudo x11vnc -storepasswd PASSWORD /home/USER/.vnc/passwd
  ```
- an unencrypted password file

  ```
  echo PASSWORD > /home/USER/.vnc/password
  ```

Respectively I executed

```
x11vnc -forever -shared -display :0 -rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd
```

for the encrypted and

```
x11vnc -forever -shared -display :0 -passwdfile /home/xubuntu/.vnc/passwd
```

for the unencrypted password file.

**Note:** Obviously I didn't do both in parallel. Also password typo is impossible due to the simplicity of the password (something like "abcd").

Both yielded the following log in the SSH terminal:

```
x11vnc -forever -shared -display :0 -passwdfile /home/xubuntu/.vnc/passwd

30/03/2022 10:38:02 x11vnc version: 0.9.16 lastmod: 2019-01-05  pid: 6641
30/03/2022 10:38:02 Using X display :0
30/03/2022 10:38:02 rootwin: 0x53b reswin: 0x3800001 dpy: 0xc07a6840
30/03/2022 10:38:02
30/03/2022 10:38:02 ------------------ USEFUL INFORMATION ------------------
30/03/2022 10:38:02 X DAMAGE available on display, using it for polling hints.
30/03/2022 10:38:02   To disable this behavior use: '-noxdamage'
30/03/2022 10:38:02
30/03/2022 10:38:02   Most compositing window managers like 'compiz' or 'beryl'
30/03/2022 10:38:02   cause X DAMAGE to fail, and so you may not see any screen
30/03/2022 10:38:02   updates via VNC.  Either disable 'compiz' (recommended) or
30/03/2022 10:38:02   supply the x11vnc '-noxdamage' command line option.
30/03/2022 10:38:02
30/03/2022 10:38:02 Wireframing: -wireframe mode is in effect for window moves.
30/03/2022 10:38:02   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
30/03/2022 10:38:02   errors, etc) it may be disabled:
30/03/2022 10:38:02    - use '-nowf' to disable wireframing completely.
30/03/2022 10:38:02    - use '-nowcr' to disable the Copy Rectangle after the
30/03/2022 10:38:02      moved window is released in the new position.
30/03/2022 10:38:02   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
30/03/2022 10:38:02   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to
30/03/2022 10:38:02   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
30/03/2022 10:38:02   periodic repaints.
30/03/2022 10:38:02
30/03/2022 10:38:02 XFIXES available on display, resetting cursor mode
30/03/2022 10:38:02   to: '-cursor most'.
30/03/2022 10:38:02   to disable this behavior use: '-cursor arrow'
30/03/2022 10:38:02   or '-noxfixes'.
30/03/2022 10:38:02 using XFIXES for cursor drawing.
30/03/2022 10:38:02 GrabServer control via XTEST.
30/03/2022 10:38:02
30/03/2022 10:38:02 Scroll Detection: -scrollcopyrect mode is in effect to
30/03/2022 10:38:02   use RECORD extension to try to detect scrolling windows
30/03/2022 10:38:02   (induced by either user keystroke or mouse input).
30/03/2022 10:38:02   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
30/03/2022 10:38:02   errors, etc) it may be disabled via: '-noscr'
30/03/2022 10:38:02   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
30/03/2022 10:38:02   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to
30/03/2022 10:38:02   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
30/03/2022 10:38:02   periodic repaints.
30/03/2022 10:38:02
30/03/2022 10:38:02 XKEYBOARD: number of keysyms per keycode 7 is greater
30/03/2022 10:38:02   than 4 and 51 keysyms are mapped above 4.
30/03/2022 10:38:02   Automatically switching to -xkb mode.
30/03/2022 10:38:02   If this makes the key mapping worse you can
30/03/2022 10:38:02   disable it with the "-noxkb" option.
30/03/2022 10:38:02   Also, remember "-remap DEAD" for accenting characters.
30/03/2022 10:38:02
30/03/2022 10:38:02 X FBPM extension not supported.
Xlib:  extension "DPMS" missing on display ":0".
30/03/2022 10:38:02 X display is not capable of DPMS.
30/03/2022 10:38:02 --------------------------------------------------------
30/03/2022 10:38:02
30/03/2022 10:38:02 Default visual ID: 0x21
30/03/2022 10:38:02 Read initial data from X display into framebuffer.
30/03/2022 10:38:02 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/4096
30/03/2022 10:38:02
30/03/2022 10:38:02 X display :0 is 32bpp depth=24 true color
30/03/2022 10:38:02
30/03/2022 10:38:02 Autoprobing TCP port
30/03/2022 10:38:02 Autoprobing selected TCP port 5901
30/03/2022 10:38:02 Autoprobing TCP6 port
30/03/2022 10:38:02 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
30/03/2022 10:38:02 Autoprobing selected TCP6 port 5901
30/03/2022 10:38:02 listen6: bind: Address already in use
30/03/2022 10:38:02 Not listening on IPv6 interface.
30/03/2022 10:38:02
30/03/2022 10:38:02 Xinerama is present and active (e.g. multi-head).
30/03/2022 10:38:02 Xinerama: number of sub-screens: 1
30/03/2022 10:38:02 Xinerama: no blackouts needed (only one sub-screen)
30/03/2022 10:38:02
30/03/2022 10:38:02 fb read rate: 230 MB/sec
30/03/2022 10:38:02 fast read: reset -wait  ms to: 10
30/03/2022 10:38:02 fast read: reset -defer ms to: 10
30/03/2022 10:38:02 The X server says there are 10 mouse buttons.
30/03/2022 10:38:02 screen setup finished.
30/03/2022 10:38:02

The VNC desktop is:      SZA-DT043-L-VM0:1
PORT=5901

******************************************************************************
Have you tried the x11vnc '-ncache' VNC client-side pixel caching feature yet?

The scheme stores pixel data offscreen on the VNC viewer side for faster
retrieval.  It should work with any VNC viewer.  Try it by running:

    x11vnc -ncache 10 ...

One can also add -ncache_cr for smooth 'copyrect' window motion.
More info: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-client-caching
```

One thing I noticed is that at least in the case of creating an unencrypted password file running `x11vnc` with `sudo` yields an error

```
30/03/2022 10:46:06 x11vnc version: 0.9.16 lastmod: 2019-01-05  pid: 6708
No protocol specified
30/03/2022 10:46:06 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed.
30/03/2022 10:46:06 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
No protocol specified

30/03/2022 10:46:06 ***************************************
30/03/2022 10:46:06 *** XOpenDisplay failed (:0)

***x11vnc was unable to open the X DISPLAY ":0", it cannot continue
***There may be "Xlib:" error message above with details about the failure

 Some tips and guidelines
 ...
```

I don't know how this affects the problem I am having but thought it might provide some insight to the more knowledgeable folks around here.

Since it's an internal company network I am not worried about someone breaking into my VM (which is meant to be disposable anyway). I will try to setup X11VNC without any authentication (if possible) but even if that works I am still interested into the cause of the issue at hand.

Comment: Which port do you use to connect? x11vnc says it's running on port 5901, maybe there's another server running on port 5900?

Comment: I checked and nothing runs. Tried to even specify the port manually and still. When I was using XRDP and Remote Desktop Connection and selecting Xvnc for example I couldsee that the connection is established but for some reason (it literally said "some problem" LOL) it then got disconnected.

Comment: I actually remembered that I use cockpit, which has a functional VNC. I need to see if that doesn't lead to some conflict.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was quite ridiculous. I am using The TigerVNC Viewer. Apparently it expects port 5900 (I hope, this is the default VNC port) but my x11vnc always starts at 5901. All I had to do was add the port. In case someone else stumbles across this inconvenience use `<REMOTE_MACHINE_IP_ADDR>:<PORT>` to access your machine in case the port is not 5900.